# How to Integrate ReactCssTransitionGroup with animate.css?

Tags: css, animation, reactjs, animate.css

I am just Trying to Integrate animate.css with react transition group.Yes I know there is already one question is there.But that is no more working.I need a working example.
This is my Try

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={{enter: "animated", enterActive: "bounce", leave: "animated",leaveActive: "tada"}}>
    {this.props.children}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

Answer (score 8):

example: animate.css with react transition group [Jsfidle](http://jsbin.com/yebevozuja/1/edit?js,output)

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={items: ['hello', 'world', 'click', 'me']};
    }
    handleAdd() {
        let {items} = this.state
        this.setState({items: [...items, 'new-element'+(items.length+1)]});
    }
    handleRemove(i) {
        var newItems = this.state.items.slice();
        newItems.splice(i, 1);
        this.setState({items: newItems});
    }
    render() {
        var items = this.state.items.map((item, i)=>
        <div key={item} className="block" onClick={this.handleRemove.bind(this, i)}>
        {item}
        </div>
    );
    return (
        <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleAdd.bind(this)}>Add Item</button>
        <CSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName={{
            enter: "animated",
            enterActive: "rubberBand",
            leave: "animated",
            leaveActive: "fadeOutRight"
        }}>
        {items}
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
    );
}


}
```